# How to write clean integration tests

Tags: go, testing, integration-testing

I want to write an integration test using Go and MySQL. But I confused how to do this clean. I have 4 functions: create, get, update, and delete. Is it a good practice if I just have one test function to test all my code? For example:

```
func TestCRUD(t *testing.T){
    t.Run("success case", func(t *testing.T){
         // call create func

         // call update func

         // call get func

         // call delete func
    })
}
```

If I have code like above, I just have one test function to test all my code. If I want to add a test case, I just add to `TestCRUD()` function. Is it a good practice?

Or should I write test function for each CRUD function? So I have 4 test functions and every test function also have many test cases. How can I write my integration test clean?

Comment: That really depends. The natural thing would be to do an individual test for each of the four methods. Unless there is good reason to not do it, e.g. if you use the stuff you created to get and delete afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you think in maintainability and clean code, IMHO I would recommend you to test each CRUD functions in a different test.

Regarding your question about multiple test cases I would say that a good approach is to use DDT (data-driven-testing or table-driven-testing). Something like:

```golang
func Test_create(t *testing.T) {
    type args struct {
        // Define here your function arguments
        arg1 string,
        arg2 string,
    }
    tests := []struct {
        name string
        args args
        want bool // Your possible function output
    }{
    // TODO: Add test cases.
    }
    for _, tt := range tests {
        t.Run(tt.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            if got := create(tt.args.id); got != tt.want {
                t.Errorf("create() = %v, want %v", got, tt.want)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Using [gotests](https://github.com/cweill/gotests) you can generate clean and nice tests for your functions.